# Searching a string in perl for x number of occurrences of a character in a IF statement

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, if-statement

I'm trying to use perl to find the number of periods on a line and if it contains the number I have defined then to group portions of a line together.

Here is what I have so far

```
        if (($lines [0] =~ /./) ==3){
            $lines [3] = $lines [0][3..-1]
                if ($lines [2] =~ /'get'/);
                    print Output "qa;$lines[2];get\n"
```

I feel like I'm close buy not close enough.

Here is a sample of the text file I am reading from, but what I have is not matching.

```
...State  [ ]
.....County  [ ]
.......City  [ get set clear ]
.......ZIP  [ get detail ]
```

The goal is for the output to look something like this when I'm done. I really only want get commands right now.

> qa;State;County;City get

But I can't seem to get it to match the periods. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If your regex should match a "." then it must be `/\./`. In a regex the "." stands for a any old char. So you must mask it by `\`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really that close, actually. Here are some pointers to get you in the right direction:
`m//` does not return how many times a match was found.  In scalar context (like comparing it to a number as you are), it returns true or false, depending on whether a single match was found at all.

In a list context, the `m//` would return all the matches, but you'd still need to assign that list to an array and then find the size of the array, in order to get a count of all the matches

you need to escape the period in the pattern match, as that is a special character

Strings are not character arrays. You cannot refer to `$lines[3]` as though it's an array of characters by putting another set of `[ ]` subscripts on the end.  There are functions that help you get pieces of strings.  Look into `substr`, for example.  (And even if it was, `[3..-1]` would not be a valid subscript, even though -1 does represent the last index of an array)

Get rid of the single quotes in the second pattern match.  That's saying you literally want to look for the string: single quote, g, e, t, single quote.

Good luck to you!